# Compiler variance in function template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

The following program:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, bool b>
struct S{
    S() = default;
    
    template<bool sfinae = true,
             typename = std::enable_if_t<sfinae && !std::is_const<T>::value>>
    operator S<T const, b>() { return S<T const, b>{}; }
};

template<typename T, bool b1, bool b2>
void f(S<const std::type_identity_t<T>, b1>,
                                 // ^- T in non-deduced context for func-param #1 
       S<T, b2>)
      // ^- T deduced from here
{}                         

int main() {
    S<int, true> s1{};
    S<int, false> s2{};
    f(s1, s2);
}
```

is accepted by GCC (11.2) but rejected by Clang (13) and MSVC (19.latest), all for `-std=c++20` / `/std:c++20` ([DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/9TaxjjhKz)).

- What compiler is correct here?

Comment: I'm adding a self-answer which I _think_ may be accurate, which I found whilst writing up the question, but I'm hoping for (at least!) a second opinion.

Comment: `bool x` is indeed deducible, but `x` cannot be deduced in `S<const int, x>` from `S<int, true>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is governed by [[temp.deduct.call]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.call), particularly [/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.call#4):

> In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument values that will make the deduced `A` identical to `A` (after the type `A` is transformed as described above). However, there are three cases that allow a difference: [...]

In the OP's example, `A` is `S<const int, true>` and the (transformed) `A` is `S<int, int>`, and none of these [three] cases applies here, meaning deduction fails.

We may experiment with this by tweaking the program such that the deduced `A` vs tranformed `A` difference falls under one of the three cases; say [[temp.deduct.call]/4.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.call#4.3)

> - If `P` is a class and `P` has the form simple-template-id, then the transformed `A` can be a derived class `D` of the deduced `A`. [...]

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, bool b>
struct S : S<const T, b> {};

template<typename T, bool b>
struct S<const T, b> {};

template<typename T, bool b1, bool b2>
void f(S<const std::type_identity_t<T>, b1>, S<T, b2>){}                         

int main() {
    S<int, true> s1{};
    S<int, true> s2{};
    f(s1, s2);
}
```

This program is correctly accepted by all three compilers ([DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/KffEcddaa)).

Thus, GCC most likely has a bug here, as the error argued for above is diagnosable (not ill-formed NDR). As I could not find an open bug for the issues, I've filed:

- [Bug 103333](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103333) - [accepts-invalid] function template argument deduction for incompatible 'transformed A' / 'deduced A' pair

---

We may also note that [[temp.arg.explicit]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.arg.explicit#7) contains a special case where implicit conversions are allowed to convert an argument type to the function parameter type:

> Implicit conversions ([conv]) will be performed on a function argument to convert it to the type of the corresponding function parameter **if the parameter type contains no template-parameters that participate in template argument deduction**.

This does *not* apply in OP's example, though, as the (function) parameter type `S<const std::type_identity_t<T>, b1>` contains also the (non-type) template parameter `b1`, which participates in template argument deduction.

However in the following program:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct S{
    S() = default;
    
    template<bool sfinae = true,
             typename = std::enable_if_t<sfinae && !std::is_const<T>::value>>
    operator S<T const>() { return S<T const>{}; }
};

template<typename T>
void f(S<const std::type_identity_t<T>>, S<T>) {}                         

int main() {
    S<int> s1{};
    S<int> s2{};
    f(s1, s2);
}
```

the (function) parameter type is `A<std::type_identity_t<T>>`, and the only template parameter in it is `T` which does not participate in template argument deduction for that parameter-argument pair (`P`/`A`). Thus, [temp.arg.explicit]/7 do apply here and the program is well-formed.